# JavaScript understanding NeDB (update query)

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, node-modules, nedb

I'm learning js database called NeDB (Node.js) https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb
Got confused on update docs.

Database before update

```
{"p_id":"1","rank":"0","_id":"fXBIrW8pp8y5M9zg"}
{"$$indexCreated":{"fieldName":"p_id","unique":false,"sparse":false}}
```

Js code

```
db.update({p_id: "1"}, {$set: {rank: "1"}}, {});
db.update({p_id: "1"}, {$set: {rank: "1"}}, {});
```

Database after update

```
{"p_id":"1","rank":"0","_id":"fXBIrW8pp8y5M9zg"}
{"$$indexCreated":{"fieldName":"p_id","unique":false,"sparse":false}}
{"p_id":"1","rank":"1","_id":"fXBIrW8pp8y5M9zg"}
{"p_id":"1","rank":"1","_id":"fXBIrW8pp8y5M9zg"}
```

Restart programm

```
{"p_id":"1","rank":"1","_id":"fXBIrW8pp8y5M9zg"}
{"$$indexCreated":{"fieldName":"p_id","unique":false,"sparse":false}}
```

So, nedb doesn't modified docs but creates a new one. I'm afraid to imagine what will happen if there are a lot of users and update requests. When I restart the code it removes the matches and db looks okay. Just want to know if it okay or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but looks like you misplaced the types here.
In your database `p_id` field has String value `"1"` but for update clause you're using Number `1`. Please change `1` to `"1"` in your code and try again

Comment: Thank you I made a typo here. All fields has string type.The question is still relevant.